# Как объединить фреймы с применением стилей?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Пытаюсь поменять у ячеек цвет в зависимости от условия `styled = result2.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v != v else 'red')`

```py
df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[1, 2, 3, 14, 21]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5],axis=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 9, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)                     

result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result2 = df2.loc[df2.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result3 = df1.loc[df1.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result4 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]

styled = result2.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v != v '' else 'red')
styled1 = result4.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v != v else 'red')

datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result3]], axis=0)
datafr1 = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [datafr, styled, styled1]], axis=1)


datafr1.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
                startcol=0, header=None, index=False)
```

но при объединение фреймов программа падает с ошибкой

> AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

[Входные таблицы и ожидаемый результат с подсвеченными расхождениями относительно df1](https://transfiles.ru/hv1b1)

Если сначала объединять

```py
result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result2 = df2.loc[df2.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result3 = df1.loc[df1.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result4 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]


datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result3]], axis=0)
datafr1 = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [datafr, result2, result4]], axis=1)
                
styled = datafr1.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v == '' else 'red')    

styled.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
                startcol=0, header=None, index=False)
```

то падает с ошибкой

> '`Styler.apply` and `.applymap` are not compatible with non-unique index or columns.'

Comment: а если сначала делать объединение, а уже потом применение стилей?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @SergFSM дополнил вопрос если сначала объединять.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, вы сравниваете переменную с самой собой - какой результат вы ожидаете? ;) PS я не берусь давать ответ без воспроизводимого примера данных - уверен на 90%, что это обернётся потерей времени как моего так и вашего

Comment: судя по ошибке, у вас в датафрейме есть не уникальные либо индексы, либо колонки

Comment: @MaxU дополнил вопрос кодом для воспроизведения, а так же ссылкой на входные данные и ожидаемый результат. Повторюсь хочу получить, что бы фон у ячеек в которых находятся расхождения с df1 менялся. Поэтому и условие такое задал lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v != v else 'red'что в моём понимании если df1 не равен df2 то у расхождений поменять фон ячеек.

Comment: @SergFSM что значит не уникальными вроде все элементы тоблиц разные?

Comment: в `datafr1` не должно быть строк с одинаковыми индексами и столбцов с одинаковыми названиями

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, со входными данными разобрались! :) Теперь давайте разберемся с тем что вы сравниваете. Что такое переменные `result` - `result4`, какие из них вам нужны. и что именно вы в них сравниваете? Также я не понимаю по какому принципу вы располагаете фреймы в результирующем (PNG) файле...

Comment: @MaxU result result4 в них помещается результат сравнения 2-х фреймов. Нужны все так как я сравниваю 2 таблицы с 3 й. df1 с df2  и df1 с df3. Сравниваю в них слова и цыфры, название товара и его количество. Размещаю по принципу результат df1 и df2 в первом сравнение должен распологаться в первом столбце а результат второго сравнения df1 и df3 под ним.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, что-то я запутался в ваших фреймах. Вот вам пример подкрашивания ячеек DataFrame  для более простого случая: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53834561/5741205 Попробуйте разобраться и переписать для ваших данных...